# jQuery : How to split the radio value and put it into a separate field

Tags: jquery, string, onclick, split, int

I'm having a dependable `input#total` which is triggered by a radio box. When a radio box is clicked, its value is revealed in an `input#total`.

Now I need to split the value `(1500|xx)` into two separate elements. But I can't make it happen. Here's my code:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=radio][name=rate]").click(function(){
       $("#total").val(this.value);
    }); 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="rate" value="10000|nc" id="rate1" />
<input type="radio" name="rate" value="15000|eb" id="rate2" />
<input type="radio" name="rate" value="17500|ss" id="rate3" />
```

From the codes above. I need to do these things.

1. Put the first array of input#rate into input#total
2. Put another value into a hidden input called input#rate_type

The first thing is done perfectly. But the second isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: **[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/JpX6E/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input[type=radio][name=rate]").click(function () {
    var arr = this.value.split('|');
    $("#total").val(arr[0]);
    $("#rate_type").val(arr[1]);
  });
});
```

Use `.split()` to split strings

Comment: A.V This is what I'm talking about. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome..! Happy to be Helpful.. :)